# Mostrar el "value" de un botón al abrir el modal

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de abrir un mismo modal, pero que contiene diferente información. Esto está dentro de un `ng-repeat` y el modal fuera.

La idea es que el value que estoy obteniendo en el botón se me muestre en el modal.

*Se que podría incluir el modal dentro del ng-repeat, y así generar los mismos modales y con distinta información pero se generará mucho código html*.

Mi botón es el siguiente:

```
<button ng-show="{{item.estado}} == false" 
type="button" data-dismiss="modal"  
data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#myModal2" 
value="{{item.nombre}}"
ng-click="mostrar={{item.nombre}}">Desbloquear</button>
```

Mi modal es el siguiente:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
       <div id="modalDesbloquear" class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
             <div class="col-xs-12  text-center">
                <h2> 
¿Desbloquear lo siguiente {{mostrar}} <!-- Aquí deberia mostrarme el nombre -->...?
                </h2>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12  text-center">
             <button class="submit-button center-item" ng-click="">
             Desbloquear
             </button>
             <button class="submit-button center-item" data-dismiss="modal">
            Cancelar
             </button>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Buscando encontré como resolver esa duda. Les comparto la información por si la llegan a necesitar.

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $('#modalAlumno').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {    
     var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data().id;
      $(e.currentTarget).find('#bookId').val(id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h2>Ejemplo pasar parametros al Bootstrap modal desde el llamador</h2>

<br />

<a id="alumno" 
data-target="#modalAlumno" 
data-toggle="modal" 
data-id="454365346"
href="#" 
class="sepV_a"
title="Agregar alumnos">
<i class="icon-eye-open"></i> Agregar alumno </a>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalAlumno">
  <div class="modal-header" style="background:gray;">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>New Tasks</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" style="background:gray;">
    <input type="text" name="bookId" id="bookId" value="" />

  </div>
</div>
```